# go-twitter API extracting video URL

Tags: go, twitter

The end goal here is:

1. A user mentions my app's handle on twitter in some tweet's reply
2. My script fetches the original tweet's ID
3. receives its json response and extracts the actual video URL from it.

My problem:

I am able to get to the point where I can print tweet.Text but anything further than that throws a memory address related error. I am new to Go and haven't really used pointers before, so I am guessing problem lies somewhere in there.

My code (ignore the comments in it, I pasted it as it is so you can refer to the error easily) ->

```
// ExtendedEntity is a []MediEntity, now we need to figure out how to access the details in it
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/dghubble/go-twitter/twitter"
    "github.com/dghubble/oauth1"
)

func main() {
    config := oauth1.NewConfig("asd", "asd")
    token := oauth1.NewToken("asd-V65ynQCN5vxWi72MGqfwF7WqYqdUZh", "asd")
    httpClient := config.Client(oauth1.NoContext, token)
    client := twitter.NewClient(httpClient)

    params := &twitter.StreamFilterParams{
        Track: []string{"@bulundindia1337"},
        // StallWarnings: twitter.Bool(true),
    }

    stream, _ := client.Streams.Filter(params)
    // fmt.Printf("%T", stream)
    // v := <-stream.Messages
    // fmt.Println(v)

    demux := twitter.NewSwitchDemux()
    demux.Tweet = func(tweet *twitter.Tweet) {
        fmt.Println("text > ", tweet.Text)
        fmt.Println("tweet ID > ", tweet.ID)
        parentTweetID := tweet.InReplyToStatusID
        fmt.Println("Parent tweet id > ", parentTweetID)
        a := parseURL(parentTweetID, client)
        fmt.Println(a)
        // fmt.Println(parentTweet.ExtendedTweet.ExtendedEntities)
        //fmt.Println(parentTweet.Text)
        //fmt.Println(parentTweet.ExtendedEntities)
    }

    for message := range stream.Messages {
        demux.Handle(message)
    }
}

func parseURL(tweetID int64, c *twitter.Client) twitter.MediaEntity {
    status, _, err := c.Statuses.Show(tweetID, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    return status.ExtendedEntities.Media[0]
}
```

The output when I run the stream ->

```
nish@b0x:~/Documents/go/twitube$ go run main.go 
text >  @thevirdas @netflix_in @TheWeirdass @EmmayEntertain @ApplauseSocial @Nikgonsalves @nikkhiladvani @nairsameer… t.co/LZ5iKKU8Ku
tweet ID >  1247376867046424578
Parent tweet id >  1246007863895449600
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x8 pc=0x669a8a]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.parseURL(0x114ab58cf2d4e000, 0xc0000ef700, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
        /home/nish/Documents/go/twitube/main.go:50 +0xda
main.main.func1(0xc00009e000)
        /home/nish/Documents/go/twitube/main.go:33 +0x243
github.com/dghubble/go-twitter/twitter.SwitchDemux.Handle(0x7119e8, 0xc00005af00, 0x7119f8, 0x711a00, 0x711a08, 0x711a10, 0x711a18, 0x711a20, 0x711a28, 0x7119c8, ...)
        /home/nish/Documents/go/src/github.com/dghubble/go-twitter/twitter/demux.go:55 +0x22e
main.main()
        /home/nish/Documents/go/twitube/main.go:41 +0x265
exit status 2
```

The go-twitter package URL -> https://godoc.org/github.com/dghubble/go-twitter/twitter#ExtendedEntity

I'd appreciate if you can point me in the right direction!

Comment: If line `50` is this `return status.ExtendedEntities.Media[0]` than that means that either `status` is `nil` and therefore the `status.ExtendedEntities` selector expression would panic, or `ExtendedEntities` is `nil` and therefore the `ExtendedEntities.Media` selector expression would panic, or `Media` is either `nil` or has no elements in it, i.e. length is zero and therefore indexing the slice would cause panic. Also note, that while the error returned from `c.Statuses.Show` seems to be `nil` (since the print is not in the output), you should never "just continue" when encountering an error.

Comment: Thank you @mkopriva. I actually executed my other python script on the same tweet and there is a media (mp4) file. I am trying to figure out exactly how would i get the raw json response and check if the go library is even processing the media output?

Comment: @nish, Did you figure it out?